# Electron entitlements error "ITMS-90287" when submitting to app store

Tags: macos, app-store, electron, appstore-sandbox

Im trying to package up my electron app with electron-packager and submit to the app store, but App developer keeps failing with 2 errors. My entitlements are not matching its saying, but I have no idea where I am going wrong.

Errors:

> ERROR ITMS-90287: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements
> in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained
> in the provisioning profile. The bundle contains a key that is not
> included in the provisioning profile:
> 'com.apple.developer.team-identifier' in
> 'com.comp.app.pkg/Payload/App.app/Contents/MacOS/App'."
>
> ERROR ITMS-90287: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements
> in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained
> in the provisioning profile. The bundle contains a key that is not
> included in the provisioning profile:
> 'com.apple.application-identifier' in
> 'com.comp.app.pkg/Payload/App.app/Contents/MacOS/App'."

Entitlements Parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Entitlements Child:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: did you figure this out? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @prabhash Did you guys figure that out? Having the same issue